# Thinking Sphinx Application Wide Search and Dealing with Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

The use case is this:

I'd like to let my user search from a single text box, then on the search results page organize the results by class, essentially.

So for example, say I have the following models configured for Thinking Sphinx: `Post`, `Comment` and `User`. (In my situation i have about 10 models but for clarity on StackOverflow I'm pretending there are only 3)

When i do a search similar to: `ThinkingSphinx.search 'search term', :classes => [Post, Comment, User]` I'm not sure the best way to iterate through the results and build out the sections of my page.

My first inclination is to do something like:

1. Execute the search
2. Iterate over the returned result set and do a result.is_a?(ClassType)
3. Based on the ClassType, add the item to 1 of 3 arrays -- `@match_posts`, `@matching_comments`, or `@matching_users`
4. Pass those 3 instance variables down to my view

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes down to what's useful for people using your website. Does it make sense to have the same query run across all models? Then `ThinkingSphinx.search` is probably best, especially from a performance perspective.

That said, do you want to group search results by their respective classes? Then some sorting is necessary. Or are you separating each class's results, like a GitHub search? Then having separate collections may be worthwhile, like what you've already thought of.

At a most basic level, you could just return everything sorted by relevance instead of class, and then just render slightly different output depending on each result. A case statement may help with this - best to keep as much of the logic in helpers, and/or possibly partials?

Comment: Hi Pat, thank you for answering.  I'm a little confused by your second and third paragraphs though.  With regards to paragraph 2, i'm trying to make search as Easy as possible for my users.  1 search bar, type in whatever.. then view the results organized by Classes essentially. ie Posts that matched your search, Authors names that matched your search, Comments that matched your search etc etc. I guess my question is HOW do i effectively & efficiently sort out the results like that?  In paragraph 3 it seems no different from paragraph 2... it's just... Figure out the @ view render vs elsewhere

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you want to sort by class name and then relevance within each class set. http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/813de527037534bd/6c6d862554d7eb64?lnk=gst&q=sort+by+class#6c6d862554d7eb64 has an example of how to do this.

Comment: And then I'd have a helper which takes an argument (a search result) and renders a specific partial. Of course, you could just name partials so they match what Rails expects (`app/views/model_name/_model_name.html.erb`) and call `render result` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 models to search from then why don't you use only  `model.search` instead of `ThinkingSphinx.search` . This would resolve your problem of performing `result.is_a?`. That means easier treatment to the way you want to display results for each `model`.

Comment: That is a good point but a few things come to mind: 1- in my app i have more like 10 models (updated the initial question). 2- Would your method cause ThinkingSphinx to run 3 searches of it's index rather than a single query?   I'm looking to search a lot of text so performance is important to me. thanks.